# Excel VBA - run-time error'438'. Object doesnt support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine

I have an excel sheet that gives me run-time

> Error '438'. Object doesn't support this property or method. It has been working fine until now.
> Any help is much appreciated.

When I press debug this part of the code : `Selection.OnAction = "ADDOTHERMATL"` is highlighted in yellow.

```
Dim QtyTblRange As String
              QtyTblRange = Worksheets("Errors").UsedRange.Offset(MaxRowNum, 0).Resize(2, (n + 2)).Address
        Worksheets("Errors").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Worksheets("Errors").Range(QtyTblRange), , xlYes).Name = "QtyErrors"
    
          MaxRow = Worksheets("JobNumConvert").Range("C" & Worksheets("JobNumConvert").Cells(Worksheets("JobNumConvert").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Address
          Sheets("JobNumConvert").Range("C3:" & MaxRow).Copy
          
          MaxRow = Worksheets("Errors").Range("A" & Worksheets("Errors").Cells(Worksheets("Errors").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Address
          Sheets("Errors").Range(MaxRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
         
          Worksheets("Errors").ListObjects("QtyErrors").Range.AutoFilter Field:=(n + 1), Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlAnd
         
               Worksheets("Errors").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
               
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Syteline - Job Materials").ListObjects("JobAggregateTable").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        Worksheets("Syteline - Job Materials").ListObjects(1).AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
        Worksheets("Errors").Buttons.Add(350, 10, 200, 25).Select
        ***Selection.OnAction = "ADDOTHERMATL"***
        Selection.Characters.Text = "Add Other Matl to Entry Sheet"
        With Selection.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=29).Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .FontStyle = "Regular"
            .Size = 10
            .Strikethrough = False
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .OutlineFont = False
            .Shadow = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
        
        Worksheets("Errors").Range("A4").FormulaR1C1 = "BOM Errors: Results in this Table indicate that Syteline's standard BOM expects a material value where the HRB results reported none."
        Worksheets("Errors").Range("A4").Font.Bold = True
    
        Worksheets("Errors").Range(MaxRow).Offset(-2, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "Qty Errors: Results in this Table are filtered to display instances where the HRB material totals and the Entry Sheet Material totals differ."
        Worksheets("Errors").Range(MaxRow).Offset(-2, 0).Font.Bold = True
        
        Worksheets("Errors").Range("A1").Activate
    
    End Sub
    Sub ADDOTHERMATL()
    
    n = Worksheets("Errors").ListObjects("QtyErrors").ListColumns("Other Matl").Index
    
    Worksheets("Errors").ListObjects("QtyErrors").Range.AutoFilter Field:=(n), Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlAnd
    
    MaxRowNum = Worksheets("Entry Sheet").Range("B" & Worksheets("Entry Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Row + 1
    Dim OtherRows
            With Worksheets("Errors").ListObjects("QtyErrors")
            For Each Line In .Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
                OtherRows = OtherRows + Line.Rows.Count
            Next
        End With
    
            If OtherRows <= 1 Then
                Worksheets("Errors").ListObjects("QtyErrors").Sort.SortFields.Clear
                Worksheets("Errors").ListObjects("QtyErrors").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
                Worksheets("Errors").ListObjects("QtyErrors").Range.AutoFilter Field:=(n - 1), Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlAnd
                MsgBox "No Other Material(s) selected.": Exit Sub
            End If
    
        OtherRows = (OtherRows + MaxRowNum - 2)
    
           Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("B" & MaxRowNum & ":B" & OtherRows).FormulaR1C1 = 10
    
           Sheets("Errors").Range("QtyErrors[Other Matl]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
           Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("C" & MaxRowNum & ":C" & OtherRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
          
           Sheets("Errors").Range("QtyErrors[HRB Other Qty]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
           Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("E" & MaxRowNum & ":E" & OtherRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            
           Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("F" & MaxRowNum & ":F" & OtherRows).FormulaR1C1 = "LBS"
            
           Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("H" & MaxRowNum & ":H" & OtherRows).FormulaR1C1 = "MAIN"
            
           Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("I" & MaxRowNum & ":I" & OtherRows).FormulaR1C1 = "9999999"
            
           Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("J" & MaxRowNum & ":J" & OtherRows).FormulaR1C1 = "Data, Entry"
            
           Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("K" & MaxRowNum & ":K" & OtherRows).FormulaR1C1 = "Pending"
            
           Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("L" & MaxRowNum & ":L" & OtherRows).FormulaR1C1 = 1
            
           Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("M" & MaxRowNum & ":M" & OtherRows).FormulaR1C1 = 1
        
           Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("N" & MaxRowNum & ":N" & OtherRows).FormulaR1C1 = "= TODAY()-1"
        
           Sheets("Errors").Range("QtyErrors[Pallet]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
           Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("Q" & MaxRowNum & ":Q" & OtherRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
           
           Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("O" & MaxRowNum & ":O" & OtherRows).FormulaR1C1 = "=""     "" & LEFT(RC[2],5)"
           
           Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("P" & MaxRowNum & ":P" & OtherRows).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(RC[1],2), 0, """")"
        
           Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("R" & MaxRowNum & ":R" & OtherRows).FormulaR1C1 = "1"
           
           Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("G" & MaxRowNum & ":G" & OtherRows).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEFT(INDEX(Summary!C[-6],MATCH('Entry Sheet'!RC[10],Summary!C[4],0)),1)=""P"",""Poplar - STOCK"",""STOCK"")"
           
        With Sheets("Entry Sheet").UsedRange
                .Copy
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
        
        Worksheets("Entry Sheet").Range("A" & MaxRowNum & ":R" & OtherRows).Style = "40% - Accent5"
        
        Worksheets("Entry Sheet").Range("A1:R" & OtherRows).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), Header:=xlYes
    
        Worksheets("Errors").ListObjects("QtyErrors").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        Worksheets("Errors").ListObjects("QtyErrors").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        Worksheets("Errors").ListObjects("QtyErrors").Range.AutoFilter Field:=(n - 1), Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlAnd
    
    
    OtherRows = (OtherRows - MaxRowNum) + 1
    
    Worksheets("Errors").Activate
    
    MsgBox "" & OtherRows & " Other Material Entries have been successfully inserted into the Entry Sheet Results."
    
    End Sub
```

Is there any update of change to Excel. Wondering because we have never had this issue.

Comment: If there was an update, it's highly unlikely that it suddenly broke your code. Members don't just disappear between updates. More likely, `Selection` isn't the object type your code assumes it is. Don't work with `Selection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>     Worksheets("Errors").Buttons.Add(350, 10, 200, 25).Select
>     Selection.OnAction = "ADDOTHERMATL"
> ```

You're assuming that `Worksheets("Errors")` is the `ActiveSheet`, for `Selection` only ever refers to the selected object on the active sheet.

Instead, keep a reference to the added button - the `Add` method returns that object:

```
Dim button As Object
Set button = Worksheets("Errors").Buttons.Add(350, 10, 200, 25)
```

Now set its `OnAction` property:

```
button.OnAction = "ADDOTHERMATL"
```